# How to turn in FMM and get exit stamp in passport if leaving Mexico by Greyhound bus?

Tags: borders, mexico, passport-stamps, fmm-tourist-card

I entered Mexico by air and received an entry stamp and an FMM card, but am planning to leave by land. I'm going to fly into Tijuana airport and take the Greyhound bus from there to north of the border.

From what I gather, the bus will stop at the US border patrol or immigration station at San Ysidro but as far as I know there is no stop at the Mexican immigration station.

What is the procedure in this case for turning in the FMM card and getting an exit stamp in the passport?

I don't want to have any problems returning to Mexico in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As you're flying into Tijuana and crossing the border into the US there,  turn in your Forma Migratoria Multiple (FMM) at the Immigration offices at the west end of the airport building, nearer the departures area.  You use the CBX skywalk to enter the US, after arriving on a flight into Tijuana, before boarding the express bus.

Comment: He's probably not using the CBX, as he said the bus stops at San Ysidro, meaning he'll board the bus on the Mexican side

Comment: @Crazydre when you go through the Tijuana airport, you enter the US there, going through Customs and Immigration before getting on the buses. If you don't, you have to venture across the highway at San Ysidro to Migracion on the other side. He can still turn in the FMM in Tijuana before taking the bus.

Comment: Here's an update: I tried to turn in the FMM at the airport and was refused. They told me I had to turn it in at the border crossing. I tried again, but could not find the migration office at the border and ended up on the US side, where the US border agent told me it was nothing to worry about. So in the end, I did NOT turn the card in and the next time I entered Mexico some months later, the migration official said nothing about the old card. So basically I think you don't need to worry about the FMM unless you are flying out of Mexico, as they don't do checks at the land border with the US.

Comment: One one six-day trip, when I was leaving the <censored> said I had been there 180 days and had to pay the fee at the bank window then come back to turn in the FMM.  I instead got back in the van and returned to USA.  No problem on subsequent visits.